# Ubuntu program RAM and CPU OID

Tags: linux, snmp, performance-monitoring

Running on Ubuntu.
I need to monitor my program CPU and RAM , my prefer way is to monitor by SNMP.

Does someone know the OID for program CPU and RAM(not total)?

If there isnt so what is the simple way to get ? parse ps command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per-process performance information is found in `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfCPU` and ``HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem`.

Given a PID, `$PID`, you can run:

```
snmpget hostname HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem.$PID
```

Or you can walk the whole process list with

```
snmpwalk hostname HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem
```

If you want to know what processes have which PID's, use `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName`.

There are other tables in this family that have more info about each running PID.